# Form can't be closed when e.Cancel = true for DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have e.Cancel = true after an invalid date is entered (must be currect or past date), but then the Exit button's close event won't fire.  I took out the e.Canel = true statement and everything seems to work fine, but I'm concerned that this is going to cause another issue in the future.  What is the correct way to code this?

```
private void maskedTextBoxDate_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsValidInput)
        {
            toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Date";
            toolTip1.Show("The data you supplied must be a valid date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.", maskedTextBoxDate, 40, 25, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            //Now that the type has passed basic type validation, enforce more specific type rules.
            DateTime userDate = (DateTime)e.ReturnValue;
            if (userDate > DateTime.Today)
            {
                toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Date";         
                toolTip1.Show("The date can't be greater than today's date.", maskedTextBoxDate, 40, 25, 2000);
                //Cancel property: true if the event should be canceled; otherwise false
                e.Cancel = true;

            }
        }

    }
```

Exit button close event:

```
private void cmdExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: is `TypeValidationCompleted` event fired when you try to exit?

Comment: If the user doesn't enter a date I would have to say that no, it doesn't fire.  But they may tab past it to the next textbox and then it would.

Comment: I dont understand why you cancelling the TypeValidationEventArgs event? by explicitly setting the event to cancel mean you dont want to validate? Instead of doing this you can make a use of a public variable and read its value whenever and wherever its required.

Comment: This was a section of code I found on the msdn library on using the maskedtextbox and it had e.Cancel = true after the DateTime object was created.

Comment: You should tag it more specifically. Windows forms, WCF etc.

Comment: Now that I know I will do in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel the type validation event in this manner, the MaskedTextBox never loses focus. The idea is that you can't commit data to the text box that isn't valid, so it is "forcing" the user to enter valid data before proceeding. You will have to make a decision on how you want to handle unvalidated data in the text box.

One way to get around this is to set the CausesValidation property on the MaskedTextBox to false. This prevents the validation sequence from firing when the control loses focus. If you do that, you will need to trigger validation in another way, such as a button (e.g., "Save"). This might not be feasible depending on user experience you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Chek your date not in the OnExit of the Date control, but in the Close event of the form, and set e.cancel to true or false.
Anyway, it's very irritating for the user when he hasn't a way to escape from a control, often because he doesn't know th format and he just wants to escape :-)

Stéphane Halimi

Comment: In the FormClosing event I tried a if DateTime.TryParse, but this doesn't do anything to keep the user from entering a future date or an incorrect format.  How does one use vaidation inside the closing event?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Control` property named `CausesValidation`.  This indicates which controls, when given focus, will cause the previously focused control to validate.

Set `maskedTextBoxDate.CausesValidation = true`

For every parent control, namely the form and every container between it and the `maskedTextBoxDate`, set `CausesValidation = false`

This will let you close or manipulate the form without causing the control to validate.